# Apollo GraphQL Reactjs Caching, going to the cache for certain fields, querying the server for other fields of the same query

Tags: reactjs, caching, apollo-client

Currently, I have a query that initially fires containing two chunks of data.

```
gql`
  query GetWorkSummaryTiles(
    $type: WorkSummaryType!
    $assignedTo: [ID]
    $clientId: ID
    $tileIds: [String!]
  ) {
    workSummary(type: $type, assignedTo: $assignedTo, clientId: $clientId, tileIds: $tileIds) {
      tiles {
        id
        metricType
        value
        listDataType
        group
        groupOrder
        title
        subtitle
        color
        order
      }
      averageRating
      ratingCount
    }
  }
`
```

The tiles field is subject to be changed when the assignedTo field changes due to user input. On the other hand, the averageRating and ratingCount fields both will never be different due to assignedTo being different.

Is there anyway to go to the cache for averageRating and ratingCount when assignedTo changes, but still requery my server for tiles? One solution I have is breaking this up into two seperate queries, but I don't know if that is subject to make my app slower/ cause unnecessary rerenders on the initial load.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why not get the `averageRating` and `ratingCount` in some query on startup and just not ask for them again? You can fetch them again anytime with a `fetchPolicy: "cached-only"` at low cost.

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond quicker, I ended up doing that, splitting them into two seperate queries, and then just fetching those fields on startup.

Comment: Glad that worked out for you. Apologies for typo in earlier msg, should be `"cache-only"`